# Sensitivity (gradient) of function solved using RK4

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, gradient-descent, runge-kutta-methods

I am looking to solve an optimization problem, using a gradient based method. As such, I need to calculate the gradient of the objective function. The objective function, however, contains an ODE that's solved using Runge-Kutta 4th order. So I am wondering how I would analytically compute the gradient, without using finite difference.

Here's a simple example to illustrate that problem I am having. Let's assume I have an objective function that contains an ODE
$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{k t^2-y}{e^{y+t}} $$
for which *k* is the design variable, and the objective function value is *y(t=1)*, solved using RK4.

My problem is I am unsure of how I can solve for the gradient of the objective with respect to the design variable, namely 
$$ \frac{dy}{dk}(t=1) $$
I would like to solve for this analytically rather than relying on finite difference of any order.

Comment: Usually you would just compute an explicit ODE for $\frac{d}{dt} \frac{dy}{dk}$ and solve that using the same method as you used to solve the main ODE.

Answer (score 1):

Set $u=\frac{d y}{d k}$, then $u(0)=0$ if there is no previous dependence on $k$ and 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}u(t)=\frac{d}{dk}\frac{d}{dt}y=\frac{d}{dk}\frac{kt^2−y}{e^{y+t}}
=\frac{t^2-u-(kt^2−y)u}{e^{y+t}}
$$
so that you can compute the target value $u(1)$ by solving the coupled system.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the suggestion. Should this give an exact gradient when both the original ODE and the gradient is solved using the same step size? I am comparing the gradient I get vs finite difference (FD) as well as complex step (CS), CS and FD matches to 9 decimal places, while this solution only matches to 2 decimal place.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I can't say what went wrong. If the derivative is integrated **simultaneously** with $y$, that is you integrate the vector $[y,u]$, then I would expect that the derivative is as correct as the solution itself.